# Is it okay to mention my country's situation in PhD applications?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, writing, application-cover-letter

I am applying for some PhD programs, and I don't know if I should mention my country's situation in those letters, like the difficulty in being a female scientist without having a friend at court or free speech problems in my country.

Comment: What sort of "situation" are you needing to mention? Or is the country name enough to let people know, based on current news?

Comment: I wouldn't say name wouldn't be enough for some people. One of the reasons I'm applying for PhD programs outside of my country is the lack of free speech and diffucilties becoming a researcher since our current government doesn't care. It's a country from middle east with no current war going on.

Comment: Do you have one or more female mentors in your circle? And are they willing to write about the situation so that you don't need to? An especially enlightened male might do as well, of course.

Comment: Not a full answer, but I know some people who think e.g. that some restrictions on free speech (e.g. Singapore, Hong Kong to a lesser extent) is defensible, even desirable. If you bring up free speech and one of these people read your application, it can conceivably backfire.

Comment: @Allure: as far as I understand, Singapore and Hong Kong cultures value more public order and peace than individual freedoms. But it is not to the point of giving up completely freedom. Hong Kong people were protesting against the Chinese government until recently (if not still now). I am pretty sure that HK academics understand that freedom of speech is necessary for good research

Comment: @Taladris if I'm not mistaken the main kind of speech that is censored in Hong Kong is political in nature. I am not sure how that is relevant to good research in most fields.

Comment: @Allure even if what you say is true, one type of relevance is that good researchers are the sorts of people who tend to put a high value on living in a place with free speech protections (including for political speech), and have more options about where to live than the average person. So places that restrict political speech seem likely to suffer a brain drain that hurts their level of research.

Comment: @DanRomik are you sure good researchers prefer free speech protections? There are a veritable host of factors when choosing a country to base oneself in, but these countries with semifree speech have tremendous advantages. I have no personal experience with Hong Kong, but I have lived in Singapore. It has low crime rate, an efficient government, no racial tensions, excellent primary & secondary schools + healthcare system, good geographical location and timezone, etc.

Comment: @DanRomik in fact I'm pretty confident one of the people I alluded to above would be happy to settle in Singapore, were it not for there being little/no funding for their particular field of research.

Comment: @DanRomik I would also make sure we are thinking of the same kind of free speech protections. Singapore has been [criticized by Human Rights Watch for curtailing free speech](https://www.hrw.org/news/2019/01/17/singapore-free-expression-targeted), but the particular kind of free speech targeted is "deliberate online falsehoods". It's not clear to me that most people or academics think allowing QAnon-style "free speech" is good; in fact the reverse might very well be true.

Comment: To mention it is OK, it shouldn't be the main narrative.

Comment: Since you haven't answered my question about mentors, I won't make this an answer. But note that some things are better said by others than by the candidate themself. I think this may be one of those cases. I can expand this if you do have such a female mentor and give some specific advice.

Comment: There are some folks from repressive places who say that some types of free speech and free thought are no longer normative or even possible in American academia; so I would check with locals around the college who are from your area and can comment on that.  Also, you might consider Canada.  I know a number of folks that we approved citizens in Canada in the same wait-time they were able to get green cards in the US.

Comment: @allure "no racial tensions" in Singapore? Really? Not to tell you your business, but it seems the Singaporean Malay and Indian minorities might disagree with that--both in [the workplace](https://www.business-standard.com/article/pti-stories/increasing-number-of-malays-indians-feel-discriminated-at-work-in-singapore-119073001396_1.html) and [the housing market](https://qz.com/india/768706/the-racist-reality-of-house-hunting-in-singapore-sorry-your-wife-is-indian/)...

Comment: @Tiercelet good point, I should have wrote "less racial tensions" compared to some other parts of the world.

Answer (score 28):

It’s generally okay to mention it, and any person with a heart is going to feel sympathy for your situation. But it’s important that you understand that this will have zero effect on your chances of getting admitted to most PhD programs. The only possible exception is in disciplines where your background of being from a country where there is a lack of free speech and women aren’t treated well is relevant for the discipline you want to study. For example, if you applying for a PhD in political science or human rights law and want to cite your background to explain why you have the passion to study those topics, this would be a helpful narrative that could actually make an impression on the admissions committee.

But for most topics, admission is based on merit and potential to succeed in the program. If you are applying for a PhD in math, say, I suggest focusing on why you have the passion and talents to succeed in your studies in this area rather than on why you want to move to a different country, which, although it is obviously important to *you*, would have no relevance to your ability to succeed in a PhD program. Good luck!

Comment: Another exception might be if someone's demonstrated successes have come despite barriers to that success, suggesting a resiliency that would be an asset in graduate school.

Comment: Would it be relevant if she lost out on academic opportunities because she's female (say, due to systematic oppression from the government or something)?

Comment: And a broader follow up question: are PhD candidates from third world countries held to the same standard as those from first world countries? I hope not, since candidates from the former have a much more research conducive environment (and hence have more opportunities) than the latter (at least in my experience) and it doesn't seem fair to compare both candidates equally.

Comment: @justauser it may be relevant, but your framing isn’t helpful. The decision to admit someone into a graduate program is not an act of charity or a way of addressing some grave injustices in the world. The focus is on whether the person has potential to succeed. If her life’s story demonstrates that she does (which could include overcoming adverse circumstances as Bryan suggested), then that story is relevant. However, the mere fact of being deprived of academic opportunities does not demonstrate anything other than the person is probably less prepared for the rigors of a graduate program.

Comment: @justauser about your follow up question: life isn’t fair, and neither are college admissions in the sense that you are defining fairness here. The purpose of admissions is to select the most promising candidates that can make the best use of the very costly resource that is a university education. (Some people are also advocating for it to be used as a tool to correct various societal injustices, but that’s a long debate and much too complicated to discuss here. By and large, what I’m saying here is how most professors will approach the issue you are raising about country of origin.)

Comment: Some countries may have visa requirements that require international applicants to have a legitimate reason to return to their original country. In other words, if the reason for issuing the visa is for PhD study and not humanitarian, an emphasis on human rights issues may disadvantage what might otherwise be a successful application on the basis of academics alone.

Comment: @DanRomik, thanks, I think your argument makes sense.

Comment: You could definitely allude to the situation in your country without making it a focal point of your application.

Comment: "this will have zero effect on your chances" - it might have a *negative* effect if the reader gets the impression that someone is trying to appeal to emotion instead of presenting a strong case for why they'd be a good choice.

Comment: @NotThatGuy it’s very common for grad school applicants to cite irrelevant personal circumstances in their applications, usually because they are not good at judging what’s relevant rather than because they are trying to be emotionally manipulative. Professors quickly learn to ignore these things. I stand by what I said, there will be no effect, either positive or negative.

Comment: It can sound like special pleading, but if you've solved your problems by demonstrating useful skills then you can turn it into a positive: e.g. significant self-study, networking and interacting with different researchers, organising co-operation with people overseas all might be useful things for a PhD program. As other answers here say, it's important to list it as skills you've gained, not things that made you perform badly.

Comment: @DanRomik And congratulations, you have just created an iron-clad justification for an ever-harder-to-enter system of elite privilege. "Opportunity [that creates high social status] is too rare and valuable to be squandered on those less prepared; therefore anyone who was [actively discriminated against/a late bloomer/not groomed from early childhood through parental high social status] need not apply." I'm not saying this isn't how the academy thinks--just that this one comment could save thousands of hours of commissions to look into leaky pipelines etc.

Comment: @Tiercelet the justification is far from ironclad, I most certainly did not create it, and the idea that a comment on an academia.se discussion could save anyone thousands of hours, while flattering to me, is obviously absurd. In other words, I have no idea what you’re talking about…

Comment: @DanRomik apologies, I should've said "articulated," not "created." This of course isn't something you're responsible for, save in the rather abstract sense that any of us are responsible for just living in the world as it is rather than radically remaking it. (Though I will note your earlier comments at least sound like an endorsement of the underlying reasoning). Nevertheless, as you've said, the reality is that admissions (especially at the graduate level) are intended to ration opportunity rather than create it, & that's useful information for this questioner and future visitors.

Comment: @Tiercelet you’re putting a lot of words into my mouth. You are free to express your opinions, but people should be aware that literally nothing you’ve written represents my views on any topic.

Comment: @DanRomik You've said graduate education is a "very costly resource" for which the system "select[s] the most promising candidates that can make the best use of [it]", and that "being deprived of academic opportunities does not demonstrate anything other than that the person is probably less prepared" (i.e. won't make the best use of it). I don't see how it's misrepresenting you to draw the obvious conclusion that those with the best academic opportunities--i.e. wealthiest or most socially favored groups--are best prepared & thus will be selected for further enrichment through this resource.

Comment: @Tiercelet I stand behind what I said. You are free to draw your own conclusions, and others can read what I wrote and interpret it for themselves. Let’s leave it at that.

Answer (score 17):

You need to be careful in how you phrase it.

In some ways, a PhD application is similar to a job application. You need to convince people that you are the best person for the position.

After reading your application, you want the application committee to remember you as "the super-qualified candidate whom we'd love to have in our PhD program, because it will be pure pleasure to do research with them", not as "the poor person who'd take any position just to get out of their terrible country". I'm *not* saying that the latter is the case, I'm just warning that you might create this impression if you get the wording wrong.

If possible, present it as a hardship you overcame (and which, therefore, speaks for your character), not as a reason to have pity with you.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @DanRomik's answer and would like to add one exception:

One case in which mentioning it would be advisable is if you apply to work with a particular advisor (which is generally the case in Europe), and that advisor indicates an interest in working with students that come from challenging background. That indication could be a statement on their website, a membership in a particular mentorship cycle, relevant tweets, or likewise.

Answer (score 4):

This ultimately hinges on whether there is some aspect of the application where this information would be relevant.  Some application processes will ask you to write a personal statement, or ask what attracts you to the institution you are applying for, or ask you to specify if you have encountered hardships in your previous work.  In all these cases the culture and professional limitations in your home country might potentially be relevant and you could mention them.  Ultimately, you will need to judge whether those details are germane to any part of the application process for the position in question.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is good to mention it. I have never seen such statements in PhD applications (I am in math and in the USA) but I would, as a member of hiring committee, consider such applications favorably. I think that just mentioning the name of the country is not enough. It is important that you personally care about these issues.

Answer (score 0):

(Decided to upgrade this from a comment to answer)

Whenever you bring up political/ideological issues like what you describe, you need to be careful, because if you reach someone with the opposite politics/ideology it can backfire.

For example:

> female scientist without having a friend at court

If you're applying to an Afghan university, this will not work well.

Note what looks uncontroversial to you might still be controversial to people you've never met. For example,

> free speech problems

As I mentioned in the comments, I know people who think free speech is a bad idea and semifree speech is the right thing. For example, they support the national security law in Hong Kong because Hong Kong is part of China and it is natural to restrict speech that promotes secession; furthermore Hong Kong will become a full part of China in 28 years, so gradual restrictions are sensible. If you live in Hong Kong and write about free speech in your PhD application, and you reach someone who believes this, it can backfire. To [quote](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/105464/) a more loaded example:

> in most left-leaning universities arguing that you would really like to move to the US because the US, unlike your European home, allows you to buy a semi-automatic weapon with relative ease, is neither a convincing reason for a move nor will it strike brownie points on an emotional level with many faculty members.

Comment: "In most left-leaning universities arguing that you would really like to move to the US because the US, unlike your European home, allows you to buy a semi-automatic weapon with relative ease, is neither a convincing reason for a move nor will it strike brownie points on an emotional level with many faculty members."

I moved to the USA from a non-free speech country and I have not even seen a semi-automatic weapon except in European movies.

Comment: I think even in repressive regimes a lot of people think they enjoy freedom of speech and other freedoms (except for minor limitations directed only at traitors and criminals), rather than being anti-free speech. Historically, communist regimes have put great store by supporting liberation movements in third world countries, so saying "I'm a poor peasant oppressed by corrupt government" might well be a good thing even to a totalitarian regime.

Comment: @MarkSapir not to totally derail this, but that might just be because of where you live. I live in a fairly left-leaning area of North Carolina and I still definitely see semi-automatic handguns carried openly at least a few times a year (in addition to police officers, who always carry a semi-automatic handgun). If you are maybe conflating semi-automatic weapon with assault rifle, that's much less common and I've never seen one carried openly, though I have family members who own one.

Comment: @bendl: Saying that people emigrate to the US because it is possible here to  buy semi-automatic weapons is not even offensive. It is just stupid.

Comment: @MarkSapir 100% agree on that point.

Answer (score 0):

There are motivated, intelligent people in every country of the world.

There are many countries, though, in which it's *much* harder to study and travel abroad if you're a woman. It's stupid and counter-productive, but that's the way it is.

This fact can be used by recruiters from other countries: if you're a woman coming from a misogynistic culture and you apply for a PhD, it means that you probably have faced adversity, but did not give up.

You don't need to explicitly mention the difficulty in being a female scientist in your country, but you can hope that recruiters will connect the dots.