# Are Russian Ph.D. degrees accepted in the EU and USA without any additional difficulty as of 2023?

Tags: phd, russia

Russia has some good universities. E.g., SkolTech, Lomonosov, etc.

Is a Russian Ph.D. degree accepted as usual without any additional difficulty as of 2023?

For instance, are the Ph.D. graduates from Russian institutions **implicitly** or **explicitly** barred to join Western academia as a professor or a postdoc researcher?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/184401/40589

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was some confusion directly after the beginning of the war in Ukraine about what the sanctions meant for universities in Germany. Many universities there played it safe and did not hire Russians, in fear of falling foul of those sanctions. That confusion is now over. As long as you can get a visum and as long as you are not working in a sensitve area you will probably get a fair chance.

Comment: Note that this answer mentions Russians, while the question is about holders of a Russian Doctoral degree, which is not the same.

Comment: Fair enough, where you are born is not your fault, but where you choose to go is.